# R, quantmod, custom source

Tags: r, quantmod

I have financial data stream from redis and/or rabbitmq. And would like to chart it with quantmod. I found in documentation that `getSymbols` has some predefined sources (yahoo, csv and others), but need none of them. So questions:

1. How load data from custom data.frame?
2. How add new tick in case real-time translation?

In comments was said that no way to plot real-time with quantmod, so is any R package compatible with shiny for real-time plotting?

Comment: I assume that the best way is to download the data as csv file and to use quantmod's `getSymbols()` function with argument `src='csv'`.

Comment: I don't think that you can chart data with real-time ticks. In this case I hope that I'm wrong and that somebody will post an answer showing how this could be done.

Comment: See the source for `getSymbols.skeleton` (and all the other `getSymbols` 'methods') for ideas how to implement a `getSymbols` 'method' for redis and/or rabbitmq. There really isn't a nice way to plot in real-time with R, since R's plot devices are pen-and-paper (meaning the entire plot must be redrawn for each new point added). Also note that asking for a package recommendation is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Found that you can create OHLC object in quantmodm, and pass zoo object as argument, so first question solved. About real-time data - may be the one way to plot redrawable at first time.

Comment: In Shiny you can force an object to be updated at an interval, or via a push button.